# Dart: Convert int to int Function()

Tags: dart

Is there any way to convert an **int** to a **int Function()** in Dart?

For example:

```
a to ()=>a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? This function will return a function which returns the int value you provided when the method was created.

```
int Function() intToIntFunction(int i) => () => i;
```

**Updated**

You can also do this if you want the current value of the integer each time the method are called:

```
void main() {
  int a = 5;
  int Function() funA = () => a;

  print(funA()); // 5
  a++;
  print(funA()); // 6
}
```

Comment: I wanted some operator that holds the reference of that object. I don't want to modify the value..I just need the value of that variable whenever the function is called.

Comment: Even `()=>` operator could do that .. but I am looking for some other way (for the sake of my syntactic brevity) Maybe some operator that can be wrapped to any random variable

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of what you want? E.g. in another language which has the feature you want?

Comment: Pass by reference ... but I don't want to modify the value (I just need the latest value of that variable)

Comment: Hm ok. I have added another solution to my answer. Is this more what you want?

Comment: Yes that's what I said ... But I am looking for another way to do the same

Comment: Well, that is not possible unless you pack your int value inside some object.

Comment: How could that let me get the latest value of a variable that is already declared?

Comment: If the original int value are inside a object you can get a reference to this object and check inside the object for current value of the int.

Comment: But it is not really a solution. Instead, you should keep a reference to the object where the int value are inside as a class member and read the value from here when you need it.

Comment: What if the object is instantiated as a part of a statement? `Object(a,b,c)` Apart from `()=>Object(a,b,c)` is there any other alternative to store it's *blueprint*?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking about and what you mean by "blueprint" in this context.

Comment: For example `()=>Object(a,b,c)` would ensure only a object with the latest value of a,b and c gets instantiated.

Comment: Yes, since all arguments are pass by value in Dart. References to objects can be seen as a pointer address to a object and such pointer are also pass by value. There are no way in Dart to pass by reference but you can send a reference to a object which are allowed to modify its internal state. Then you get a "pass by reference" like experience.

Comment: Please let me know if you somehow find some way to do it ... maybe some data-type whose object can be instantiated by using a operator. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, the only objects which can be created by an operator would be List ([]), Map ({}) and Set (<Set>{}).

Comment: Any other operator that could do the work (even through extension methods and operator overriding would do the work)?